Windows 'print' command reports OK and does nothing once, then reports unable to initialize on subsequent calls
I'm using the print command on Windows to attempt to print a file. The exact command I'm running is as follows:
print /d:"iR-ADV C257" C:\TestPrint.txt

For any given printer, the first time I run the command, it produces the standard output C:\TestPrint.txt is currently being printed, and exits with code 0, however the printer does nothing. It does not matter if the printer name given is valid or not; the output will be the same. If the printer name is valid, no printing will occur, even if the printer is perfectly happy to print the same file when asked a different way, e.g. in file explorer, right click > print.
Every subsequent time I run the command for the same printer, the standard output will then be Unable to initialize device iR-ADV C257 (or whatever was passed to /d in the command). The exit code is 0 on these occasions as well. Specifying a different printer will give me the first messaage once, and then this message each subsequent time.
On both occasions, nothing is added to the print queue, nothing else seems to happen... I can observe no side-effects of running the command.
I'm at a loss for where to begin attempting to debug this issue as the messages I recieve from the command are inconsistent and largely unhelpful.
Relevant /j: Today is not Tuesday.
